# Creating multiple images of heatmap using pandas, seaborn?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

Currently, I am trying to output image outputs for my data.

My original source is like this:

```
total_dict = {"A" : {"A1" : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "A2" : [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]}, "B" : {"B1" : [11, 22, 13, 34, 5], "B2" : [12, 31, 42, 52, 16]},"C" : {"C1" : [12, 22, 33, 4, 5], "C2" : [42, 33, 42, 15, 6]}, "D" : {"D1" : [1, 23, 35, 4, 5], "D2" : [21, 23, 34, 5, 6]}}
```

Now, I am trying to create 4 heat maps for each sub-library: A, B, C and D.
My program is:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
for sub in total_dict:
    df = pd.DataFrame(total_dict[sub])
    image = sns.heatmap(df, cmap="YlGnBu", linewidths = 0.1, vmax = 100)
    print (image)
```

However, it does not print out 4 separate images as I expected. The final result is:
[heatmap_result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkA0F.png)

Could you please suggest me any method that I can use to get my expected 4 separate outputs as well as be able to save them in 4 separate files.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a new figure, plot the heat-map, and save the figure.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for index, sub in enumerate(total_dict):
  df = pd.DataFrame(total_dict[sub])
  # create a new figure
  fig = plt.figure()
  image = sns.heatmap(df, cmap="YlGnBu", linewidths = 0.1, vmax = 100)
  fig_name = 'test_%s.png' %(index)
  fig.savefig(fig_name)
```

Comment: Hi, I do not have such a problem. Are you sure that the indentation of the final command within the for loop, 'fig.savefig(fig_name)', is within the for loop? maybe something went wrong while copy-paste the script.

Comment: Thank you. So I use this command:
fig.savefig("%s.png" %(index))
Things are fine now

Comment: Hi,
I notice that the width of the first and last row in heat maps are only equal to half of others. Could you help me fix it?

Comment: Hi, I see what you mean. it seems to be a problem related to seaborn and matplotlib 3.1.1. I fixed it by downgrading matplotlib to 3.1.0 or updating to 3.1.2. You can read more at: https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/1773

Comment: Well thank you so much Agrioni. It is such a valued help to me

Comment: I am glad the answer helped you. Do you mind to accept the answer if it solved your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer